# Activate a process if a task is related to any opportunities

Tags: process-builder, opportunity, tasks

I'm trying to create a process that activates and updates a few fields when a task is created and the task is related to any opportunity.

I can update the fields easily, but I'm struggling to make the process only activate when a task is made and related to any opportunity.

It should only activate when:

- A task is created.
- The task is related to any opportunity.

After that it needs to update a few fields, but as I said I've got that working.

How do I create some criteria in my 'Update if related to Opportunity' decision that will check if the task has been related to any opportunity and only then update the fields?

Here's a screenshot if that helps with anything.

[image]

Comment: Activate means to want to say it fires. rght??

Comment: Yes, thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your process builder will fire when a task is created and only its related to Opportunity. Please find below screenshots for same.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! After looking at your solution I was able to find this [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Standard-Field-Record-ID-Prefix-Decoder&language=en_US&type=1) in case anyone ever has a similar problem.

Comment: yes, that will be helpful for looking the object prefix for standard objects.